# How to functional test secured pages in Symfony2?

Tags: authentication, testing, symfony, functional-testing

#### Setup and information to reproduce the problem

- Symfony2.2 application
- LiipFunctionalTestBundle
- DoctrineFixturesBundle
- FOSUserBundle

For testing enviroment I use LiipFunctionalTestBundle and generate (from DoctrineFixtures) a fake SQLite database. It's configured correctly - I've been able to succesfully test my non-secured pages.

I've created a simple secured page under `/secured/test` with this view:

```
<h2 class="username">{{ app.user.username }}</h2>
```

1. I've tried with

   - http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html

And I wanted to test this action with this assertion:

```
$client = static::createClient(array(), array(
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'myUserName'
    'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'password',
));

$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/secured/test');

$count = $crawler
         ->filter('h2.username:contains("myUserName")')
         ->count();

$this->assertTrue($count > 0);
```

The result was `Failed asserting that false is true.`

1. I've tried with

   - http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html

And I wanted to test this action with this assertion:

```
$this->logIn();

$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/secured/test');

$count = $crawler
         ->filter('h2.username:contains("myUserName")')
         ->count();

$this->assertTrue($count > 0);
```

Ofcourse I changed the logIn function to diffrent username.

The result was `Failed asserting that false is true.`

## None of these works. Whats wrong?

I've tried many other methods, but

Comment: your application uses http authentication or symfony internal with a login form & firewall ?

Comment: have you had a look at the full html the crawler returns?

Comment: I tried enableing http authentication (only in test enviroment), but I could not get it working

Comment: crawler returns redirect to login page

Comment: as you don't have http authentication but login-form and project-internal authenticationthe whole first part ( PHP_AUTH_USER , ... ) was never able to work.

Comment: what's in your $this->login() method ?

Comment: it's a copy-paste from http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html

Comment: only changed username

Comment: can you please dump the cookie being set when you regularly log into your application?

Comment: thank you for help nifr, i've finally figured it out

Comment: can you provide the solution please :) Was it the cookie?

Comment: nifr -> it wasnt the cookie, but I finally managed to debug this by dumping $this->client->getResponse()->getContent() into a file, and there i saw "Account not enabled" message which led me to the solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30587/discussion-between-loostro-and-nifr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was very simple:

In my DoctrineFixtures I've created new users.. but their accounts were not enabled.

Adding this code to fixture solved the problem:

```
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $user->setExpired(false);
    $user->setLocked(false);
```

(becouse my test was trying to log on not enabled account, the response to "submit login form" was redirect to login page)